# How do I reinstall macOS to my Mac after formatting the main drive accidentally?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, restore

I recently installed Windows to my Mac and I have just formatted my hard drive on windows mistakenly while I was making a new hard drive partition on Windows. Now I cannot boot to macOS anymore.

How do I reinstall macOS to my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear if you have one or two hard drives in your machine. Nevertheless, the only thing that comes to mind, if you can't access another Mac to make a [bootable USB drive](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372), is boot from [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314), and reinstall OSX.

To enter this mode Internet Boot Recovery, do the following:

1. In the Apple menu, choose Restart or power on your Mac.
2. As the computer restarts, hold down the <kbd>cmd/⌘</kbd>+<kbd>opt/⌥</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> combination immediately upon hearing the startup chime. Hold the keys until the animated globe appears on the screen.

From there follow the instructions and reinstall the original OS your Mac was delivered with. Then update to the latest macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to get to recovery by holding command+R upon boot? you would be able to re-install there. Assuming probably not if the entire drive was formatted since it most likely would have blown out the recovery partition as well, but worth a quick check...

If not, you could create a bootable USB of your desired OS, boot to it, and install.

Create bootable USB on another Mac: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Create in Windows via TransMac: http ://www.wikigain.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-transmac/

Boot to USB: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/09/14/how-to-start-up-mac-from-bootable-media/

Comment: really thanks guys... really helped... till now i have no idea what to do... il try to find someone who got a mac. non of my friend is using mac.. but il try to find one some how..really thanks..